# SAML Toolkit Java, samltest.id, SLO does not work

Tags: java, saml, onelogin

I try to login and logout java-saml-toolkit-jpsample
https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml
to the IdP of samltest.id.
It's metadata is hosted here:
https://samltest.id/saml/idp

Here is a summary:
https://samltest.id/download/

If it is important: Its on Windows 10 (latest), Java 11 and Tomcat 9. No errors during build and no thrown errors during execution.

For the configuration of onelogin, I set the configuration to:

```
#  If 'strict' is True, then the Java Toolkit will reject unsigned
#  or unencrypted messages if it expects them signed or encrypted
#  Also will reject the messages if not strictly follow the SAML
onelogin.saml2.strict =  false

# Enable debug mode (to print errors)
onelogin.saml2.debug =  true


#  Service Provider Data that we are deploying
#

#  Identifier of the SP entity  (must be a URI)
onelogin.saml2.sp.entityid = https://mysuperssoservice.de

# Specifies info about where and how the <AuthnResponse> message MUST be
#  returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
# URL Location where the <Response> from the IdP will be returned
onelogin.saml2.sp.assertion_consumer_service.url = http://localhost/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/acs.jsp

# SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <Response>
# message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
# HTTP-POST binding only
onelogin.saml2.sp.assertion_consumer_service.binding = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST

# Specifies info about where and how the <Logout Response> message MUST be
# returned to the requester, in this case our SP.
onelogin.saml2.sp.single_logout_service.url = http://localhost/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/sls.jsp

# SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <LogoutResponse> or sending the <LogoutRequest>
# message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
# HTTP-Redirect binding only
onelogin.saml2.sp.single_logout_service.binding = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect

# Specifies constraints on the name identifier to be used to
# represent the requested subject.
# Take a look on lib/Saml2/Constants.php to see the NameIdFormat supported
onelogin.saml2.sp.nameidformat = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified

# Usually x509cert and privateKey of the SP are provided by files placed at
# the certs folder. But we can also provide them with the following parameters

onelogin.saml2.sp.x509cert = -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\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\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----

# Requires Format PKCS#8   BEGIN PRIVATE KEY         
# If you have     PKCS#1   BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY  convert it by   openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -nocrypt -in sp.rsa_key -outform pem -out sp.pem
onelogin.saml2.sp.privatekey = -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\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\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
# Identity Provider Data that we want connect with our SP
#

# Identifier of the IdP entity  (must be a URI)
onelogin.saml2.idp.entityid = https://samltest.id/saml/idp

# SSO endpoint info of the IdP. (Authentication Request protocol)
# URL Target of the IdP where the SP will send the Authentication Request Message
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_sign_on_service.url = https://samltest.id/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO

# SAML protocol binding to be used to deliver the <AuthnRequest> message 
# to the IdP.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
# HTTP-Redirect binding only
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_sign_on_service.binding = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect

# SLO endpoint info of the IdP.
# URL Location of the IdP where the SP will send the SLO Request
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.url = https://samltest.id/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SLO

# Optional SLO Response endpoint info of the IdP.
# URL Location of the IdP where the SP will send the SLO Response. If left blank, same URL as onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.url will be used.
# Some IdPs use a separate URL for sending a logout request and response, use this property to set the separate response url
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.response.url = 

# SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <Response>
# message.  Onelogin Toolkit supports for this endpoint the
# HTTP-Redirect binding only
onelogin.saml2.idp.single_logout_service.binding = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect

# Public x509 certificate of the IdP
onelogin.saml2.idp.x509cert = -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\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\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----
#onelogin.saml2.idp.x509cert = -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\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\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----
#onelogin.saml2.idp.x509cert = -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDEjCCAfqgAwIBAgIVAPVbodo8Su7/BaHXUHykx0Pi5CFaMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMBYxFDASBgNVBAMMC3NhbWx0ZXN0LmlkMB4XDTE4MDgyNDIxMTQwOVoXDTM4MDgyNDIxMTQwOVowFjEUMBIGA1UEAwwLc2FtbHRlc3QuaWQwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCQb+1a7uDdTTBBFfwOUun3IQ9nEuKM98SmJDWaMwM877elswKUTIBVh5gB2RIXAPZt7J/KGqypmgw9UNXFnoslpeZbA9fcAqqu28Z4sSb2YSajV1ZgEYPUKvXwQEmLWN6aDhkn8HnEZNrmeXihTFdyr7wjsLj0JpQ+VUlc4/J+hNuU7rGYZ1rKY8AA34qDVd4DiJ+DXW2PESfOu8lJSOteEaNtbmnvH8KlwkDs1NvPTsI0W/m4SK0UdXo6LLaV8saIpJfnkVC/FwpBolBrRC/Em64UlBsRZm2T89cauzDee2yPUvbBd5kLErw+sC7i4xXa2rGmsQLYcBPhsRwnmBmlAgMBAAGjVzBVMB0GA1UdDgQWBBRZ3exEu6rCwRe5C7f5QrPcAKRPUjA0BgNVHREELTArggtzYW1sdGVzdC5pZIYcaHR0cHM6Ly9zYW1sdGVzdC5pZC9zYW1sL2lkcDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEABZDFRNtcbvIRmblnZItoWCFhVUlq81ceSQddLYs8DqK340//hWNAbYdjWcP85HhIZnrw6NGCO4bUipxZXhiqTA/A9d1BUll0vYB8qckYDEdPDduYCOYemKkDdmnHMQWs9Y6zWiYuNKEJ9mf3+1N8knN/PK0TYVjVjXAf2CnOETDbLtlj6Nqb8La3sQkYmU+aUdopbjd5JFFwbZRaj6KiHXHtnIRgu8sUXNPrgipUgZUOVhP0C0N5OfE4JW8ZBrKgQC/6vJ2rSa9TlzI6JAa5Ww7gMXMP9M+cJUNQklcq+SBnTK8G+uBHgPKRzBDsMIEzRtQZm4GIoHJae4zmnCekkQ==-----END CERTIFICATE-----


# Instead of use the whole x509cert you can use a fingerprint
# (openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -in "idp.crt" to generate it,
# or add for example the -sha256 , -sha384 or -sha512 parameter)
#
# If a fingerprint is provided, then the certFingerprintAlgorithm is required in order to
# let the toolkit know which Algorithm was used. Possible values: sha1, sha256, sha384 or sha512
# 'sha1' is the default value.
# onelogin.saml2.idp.certfingerprint = 
# onelogin.saml2.idp.certfingerprint_algorithm = sha256


# Security settings
#

# Indicates that the nameID of the <samlp:logoutRequest> sent by this SP
# will be encrypted.
onelogin.saml2.security.nameid_encrypted = true

# Indicates whether the <samlp:AuthnRequest> messages sent by this SP
# will be signed.              [The Metadata of the SP will offer this info]
onelogin.saml2.security.authnrequest_signed = true

# Indicates whether the <samlp:logoutRequest> messages sent by this SP
# will be signed.
onelogin.saml2.security.logoutrequest_signed = true

# Indicates whether the <samlp:logoutResponse> messages sent by this SP
# will be signed.
onelogin.saml2.security.logoutresponse_signed = true

# Indicates a requirement for the <samlp:Response>, <samlp:LogoutRequest> and
# <samlp:LogoutResponse> elements received by this SP to be signed.
onelogin.saml2.security.want_messages_signed = true

# Indicates a requirement for the <saml:Assertion> elements received by this SP to be signed.
onelogin.saml2.security.want_assertions_signed = true

# Indicates a requirement for the Metadata of this SP to be signed.
# Right now supported null (in order to not sign) or true (sign using SP private key) 
onelogin.saml2.security.sign_metadata =

# Indicates a requirement for the Assertions received by this SP to be encrypted
onelogin.saml2.security.want_assertions_encrypted = true

# Indicates a requirement for the NameID received by this SP to be encrypted
onelogin.saml2.security.want_nameid_encrypted = true

# Authentication context.
# Set Empty and no AuthContext will be sent in the AuthNRequest
# You can set multiple values (comma separated them)
onelogin.saml2.security.requested_authncontext = urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password

# Allows the authn comparison parameter to be set, defaults to 'exact'
onelogin.saml2.security.onelogin.saml2.security.requested_authncontextcomparison = exact

# Allows duplicated names in the attribute statement
onelogin.saml2.security.allow_duplicated_attribute_name = false

# Indicates if the SP will validate all received xmls.
# (In order to validate the xml, 'strict' and 'wantXMLValidation' must be true).
onelogin.saml2.security.want_xml_validation = true

# Algorithm that the toolkit will use on signing process. Options:
#  'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha384'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512'
onelogin.saml2.security.signature_algorithm = http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256

# Algorithm that the toolkit will use on digest process. Options:
#  'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#sha384'
#  'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512'
onelogin.saml2.security.digest_algorithm = http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256 

# Reject Signatures with deprecated algorithms (sha1)
onelogin.saml2.security.reject_deprecated_alg = true

# Organization
#onelogin.saml2.organization.name = SP Java 
#onelogin.saml2.organization.displayname = SP Java Example
#onelogin.saml2.organization.url = http://sp.example.com
#onelogin.saml2.organization.lang = 

# Contacts
onelogin.saml2.contacts.technical.given_name = Andreas Andreas 
onelogin.saml2.contacts.technical.email_address = andreas.andreas@andreas.com
onelogin.saml2.contacts.support.given_name = Olaf Olaf 
onelogin.saml2.contacts.support.email_address = olaf.olaf@Olaf.de
```

The metadata I shared is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" validUntil="2031-10-17T22:45:08Z" cacheDuration="PT604800S" entityID="https://mysuperssoservice.de">
  <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://localhost/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/sls.jsp"/>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/acs.jsp" index="1"/>
  </md:SPSSODescriptor>
  <md:ContactPerson contactType="technical">
    <md:GivenName>Andreas Andreas</md:GivenName>
    <md:EmailAddress>andreas.andreas@andreas.com</md:EmailAddress>
  </md:ContactPerson>
  <md:ContactPerson contactType="support">
    <md:GivenName>Olaf Olaf </md:GivenName>
    <md:EmailAddress>olaf.olaf@olaf</md:EmailAddress>
  </md:ContactPerson>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

When I start the samples project, the login works perfectly and I receive all data about the user I log in.
However, when I try to logout, the SAML Toolkit Auth-object gives the error:

> logout_not_success.urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder.

And when I look into the log of the IdP, I see the message:

> 2022-01-27 06:43:18,000 - ERROR
> [org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter:?] - Error
> decrypting encrypted key
> org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: Unwrapping
> failed    at
> org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptKey(XMLCipher.java:1533)
> Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unwrapping failed   at
> com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineUnwrap(RSACipher.java:447)
> Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error     at
> sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:379) 2022-01-27
> 06:43:18,001 - ERROR
> [org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter:?] - Failed to
> decrypt EncryptedKey, valid decryption key could not be resolved
> 2022-01-27 06:43:18,001 - ERROR
> [org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter:?] - Failed to
> decrypt EncryptedData using either EncryptedData
> KeyInfoCredentialResolver or EncryptedKeyResolver + EncryptedKey
> KeyInfoCredentialResolver 2022-01-27 06:43:18,002 - ERROR
> [org.opensaml.saml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter:?] - SAML Decrypter
> encountered an error decrypting element content
> org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.DecryptionException: Failed to
> decrypt EncryptedData     at
> org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:548)
> 2022-01-27 06:43:18,002 - WARN
> [org.opensaml.saml.saml2.profile.impl.DecryptNameIDs:?] - Profile
> Action DecryptNameIDs: Failure performing decryption
> org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.DecryptionException: Failed to
> decrypt EncryptedData     at
> org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:548)
> 2022-01-27 06:43:18,002 - WARN
> [org.opensaml.profile.action.impl.LogEvent:?] - A non-proceed event
> occurred while processing the request: DecryptNameIDFailed 2022-01-27
> 06:43:18,002 - DEBUG
> [org.opensaml.saml.common.profile.logic.DefaultLocalErrorPredicate:?]
>
> - Error event DecryptNameIDFailed will be handled with response

Do I miss something? Can you see an error in my setup?
Appreciate any kind of help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error indicates, it is not able to decrypt your message. If you dont want to encrypt and send, you can disable those settings that enable encryption like `onelogin.saml2.security.nameid_encrypted = false`. Since you haven't shown if you uploaded your key to Idp or the Idp settings, I can't tell much.

Comment: Thank you @Zincfan.
What do you mean by >> Since you haven't shown if you uploaded your key to Idp or the Idp settings <<
I showed the whole metadata I uploaded to samltest.io which is successfully parsed by their server, as the result message indicates (first block in my post).
The IdP settings I employ are integrated in the second big block and taken from their information site.
There, the SPSSODescriptor contains my key. Which further information do you need?